# SVN merge existing dir with current one

Tags: svn

I have an SVN repo that has two directories, `dirA` and `dirB`. Each of them has a `foo` subdirectory in it but `dirA`'s `foo` has lots of files and subdirectories and `dirB`'s `foo` directory only has a couple of files.

What i want to do is copy the entire content and structure of `dirA`'s `foo` into `dirB`'s `foo`, merging with the content already there.

Tried `svn cp` but only works if destination directory doesn't already exist, which is not the case.

Is there a way to do this other than `svn cp`ing each file/directory individually?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have working copies of both paths already?
Just use `cp`, then `svn rm` the old copies and `svn add` the new copies.

Are you trying to merge two remotes?
Since dirB only has a couple files, you could `svn cp` each individually.